# How to change the primary color of a JTableHeader in Windows LookAndFeel?

Tags: java, windows, jtable, look-and-feel, jtableheader

I have already created an similar post where I asked that question as EDIT. But I do not think many people will see it like that. My question is, how I change the background color of a JTableHeader (So the Colors of the columns). I know that normaly

```
table.getHeader().setBackground(Color.blue);
```

should work, but this does not work when I set the LookAndFeel on Windows look and feel. 
`com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`

Comment: What is the look and feel have you set ?

Comment: @Sambit com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use the below look and fee.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

I provide below the complete runnable sample code where you can see the Blue color table header.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableHeaderExample {
  private JFrame jFrame;

  public TableHeaderExample() {
    jFrame = new JFrame();
  }

  private void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
      //Do not use below.
//      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
//              "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void createTableWithColorHeader() {
    setLookAndFeel();
    String data[][] = {{"Sambit", "23", "1000"}, {"John", "25", "200"}};
    String column[] = {"EMP NAME", "EMP AGE", "EMP SALARY"};
    JTable jTable = new JTable(data, column);
    jTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.blue);
    jTable.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jTable);
    jFrame.add(sp);
    jFrame.setSize(300, 400);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TableHeaderExample example = new TableHeaderExample();
    example.createTableWithColorHeader();
  }
}
```

See below the image.
[image]

Also refer to the following link.
http://leo.ugr.es/elvira/devel/Tutorial/Java/uiswing/misc/plaf.html
To quote one line is

> IManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() Returns the string for
>   the one look-and-feel guaranteed to work -- the Java Look & Feel.
>   UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() Specifies the look and feel
>   for the current platform. On Win32 platforms, this specifies the
>   Windows Look & Feel

Comment: You can also refer to the following link. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: I know that this works, but I want to use the WindowsLookAndFeel cause it looks much better and also has an hover effect. It also works better with my other code (If you look on the formating). But my question was how to change the color if lookandfeel is Windows. This has to be possible. Can one see the code of the Windows LookAndFeel

Comment: Check this example. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ToolTipTable.htm

Comment: Thank your very much that helped me very much.